# BackgroundImage when using MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ContentPage, such like this:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="XXXXXX"
    Title="Title"
    BackgroundImage="bg_app.png"
    Padding="5">
```

When I use that page directly in App.Current.MainPage the BackgroundImage appears... But, when I use the same page in MasterDetailPage.Detail, the background image don't works...

When I set MasterDetailPage.BackgroundImage property... The BackgroundImage don't work too.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Why no answer? I got the exact same problem

Comment: I'm not sure if this was a problem before. But, it seems to have been fixed now. And you can directly set the BackgroundImage property in any page and have it shown in the MasterDetailPage's Detail page.